# Is there any inbuilt browser for web automation using python?

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, browser-automation

I have tried splinter for browser automation. Used firefox webdriver in splinter. But the problem is high CPU usage when the firefox loads and sometimes its hangs the gui. Please suggest me an option. I'm in a Linux box(Ubuntu) and building an app using pygtk.

Answer (score 0):

Selinum with phantomjs should be a good replacement of splinter.

Comment: phantomjs is a headless browser.right? But I need gui.